# Create table from 3 or more different tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 main tables, Table1 and Table2:

**Table1**

- Attrib_Alpha
- Attrib_1
- Attrib_2
- Attrib_3
- Attrib_4
- Attrib_5

**Table2**

- Attrib_Bravo
- Attrib_6
- Attrib_7
- Attrib_8
- Attrib_9

I will select only some records of the 2 tables using these 2 queries ($Attrib_ variables contain the records to search for):

```
SELECT Attrib_Alpha FROM Table1 WHERE Attrib_1 IN (".$Attrib_1.") AND Attrib_2 IN (".$Attrib_2.") AND Attrib_3 IN (".$Attrib_3.") AND Attrib_4 IN (".$Attrib_4.") AND Attrib_5 IN (".$Attrib_5.")

SELECT Attrib_Bravo FROM Table2 WHERE Attrib_6 IN (".$Attrib_6.") AND Attrib_7 IN (".$Attrib_7.") AND Attrib_8 IN (".$Attrib_8.") AND Attrib_9 IN (".$Attrib_9.")
```

Those 2 queries output will fill in 2 variables ($List_Alpha and $List_Bravo). These 2 arrays are used to query other tables tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4, tbl5, tbl6 (these tables have the same structure).

**tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4, tbl5, tbl6**

- Attrib_Alpha
- Attrib_Bravo
- Elem_1
- Elem_2
- Elem_3
- Elem_4
- Elem_5

The following code will directly create a Final_Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Final_Table SELECT * FROM tbl1,tbl2,tbl3,tbl4,tbl5,tbl6 WHERE Attrib_Alpha IN (".$List_Alpha.") AND Attrib_Bravo IN (".$List_Bravo.") AND Elem_1 IN (".$Elem_1.") AND Elem_2 IN (".$Elem_2.") AND Elem_3 IN (".$Elem_3.") AND Elem_4 IN (".$Elem_4.") AND Elem_5 IN (".$Elem_5.")
```

The Final_Table is structured like this:

**Final_Table**

- Attrib_Alpha
- Attrib_Bravo
- Elem_1
- Elem_2
- Elem_3
- Elem_4
- Elem_5

I am trying to add also the corresponding attributes from Table1 and Table2 to the Final_Table, so that it will look like this:

- Attrib_Alpha
- Attrib_Bravo
- Elem_1
- Elem_2
- Elem_3
- Elem_4
- Elem_5
- Attrib_1
- Attrib_2
- Attrib_3
- Attrib_4
- Attrib_5
- Attrib_6
- Attrib_7
- Attrib_8
- Attrib_9

I wanted to add another query to do this:

```
UPDATE TABLE Final_Table SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Attrib_Alpha IN (".$List_Alpha.")
UPDATE TABLE Final_Table SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Attrib_Bravo IN (".$List_Bravo.")
```

But it's not working. I'm sure there is a faster way to do all this, maybe using a more complex query, but please keep in mind that the tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4, tbl5, tbl6 are large tables (>800Mb each).

Comment: Sounds like you need a join ... http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: your `create table` statement is wrong